# Using closure to set properties gives an error

Tags: swift

I am using following code to set properties of UITextView with a closure. However it gives me following error.

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

```
let textView = UITextView {
    $0.text = "SAMPLE TEXT"
    $0.isEditable = false
    $0.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 14, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of a UITextView initializer that takes a closure argument. – Where does that code come from? Perhaps you forgot to copy something else?

Comment: Silly me :\ Thanks for the reply. I guess I had a extension and forgot to copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no initializer for `UITextView` that takes a closure argument. Try something like this instead:

```
let textView: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.text = "SAMPLE TEXT"
    tv.isEditable = false
    tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 14, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    return tv
}()
```